# Textbox Control

Tags: c#, sql

I have implemented the Autocomplete extender in my ASP.NET webpage using a Textbox. The textbox displays the name however is there a way to bind it also with the ID?

Comment: i think it is possible if u append the ID and DATA as a single string

Answer (score 0):

The way we worked around this was to actually display the data in this format "[ID] - [Description]". When a selection was made and posted, we split the text and acquired the needed info. This is the only way that I have found  so far.